# Git Reset doesn't change server version?

Tags: git, github

One of the team made a commit and pushed to the remote, we all, including the server pulled the latest version.

But now it has broken a significant piece of the application. So we:

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard

git push origin -f
```

The message after the push was:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)...forced update
```

Then I pulled on the server with:

```
git pull
```

The message it says is:

```
Already up-to-date
```

So it hasn't reverted to the one before the previous commit. On my local version it at the right commit but on the server it is still the old one.

The main (central) repo is the one on github, then there is a server version then there is my local.

Comment: To clarify, you have at least three different (but to-be-sync-ed) repos here: yours, `origin`, and some server.  Correct?

Comment: sorry yes: mine, github and server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never rewrite history to fix a bug. Instead, `revert` the breaking commit:

```
git revert HEAD
git push origin master
```

That way you undo a change from the past by going forward in time.

To fix your server you need to `reset` to your remote branch:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

where `origin` is the remote name that you have on your server and `master` is the branch you're working on.

This will bend your `master` branch to be in the same state of the `master` branch on `origin`.

Background: `pull` tries to `merge` the corresponding branch of your remote into your local one. Since the branch on the remote is "shorter" than the local one there is nothing to merge and the `merge` will simply say "okay, I am done, both branches are up to date".

Comment: Oh and `revert`ing allows you to undo commits from a few weeks ago too: `git revert <commit id>`. The way you did it will not allow this without discarding a few weeks worth of work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're doing, in picture form.

Because of the "bad commit" push, on `origin` (presumably github) you had some commits, something like this:

```
... - B - C
            \
              X   <-- HEAD=master
```

where `X` is the "bad" commit.  You've then gotten both your own repo and the server's repo in sync, so that they have this same commit-sequence.  (I drew it with this funny bend in the sequence just so that the diagrams below make more sense.)

Now on your own system, in your repo, you "rewind" the `HEAD` branch (presumably `master`, but this applies even if it's some other branch) one commit:

```
... - B - C       <-- HEAD=master
            \
              X
```

Note that commit `X` still exists (in reflog history, and on github and the server) at this point, it's just that in *your* repo, `master` points to earlier commit `C` instead.

Now when you `git push origin` it's rejected because it's not a fast-forward, so you used `-f`.  This makes the `origin` site *also* re-point `master`, so that commit `X` is dangling off into space (whether it gets garbage-collected depends on configuration; push-able servers may or may not keep reflogs).

On the server, however, the "bad" commit is still there:

```
... - B - C
            \
              X   <-- HEAD=master
```

When you go there and do `git pull`, this does a `git fetch` to pick up the new commits if there are any, and then it does a `git merge` to merge those new commits in.

There are no new commits, so `pull` adds no commits and merges nothing ... which leaves `master` pointing to commit `X`.  As far as the server knows, someone added the new commit `X` on the server, and it should hang on to it, because maybe whoever added it will come along and push it back to the `origin` repo on github. :-)

---

You *can* go over to the server and do the same `git reset` command, to back up *its* idea of which commit `master` should name.  In general, though, [Nils Werner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21114212/1256452) is right: you should have done a `git revert` on your repo, and pushed that.  Pictorally, this would do:

```
... - B - C - X - unX  <-- HEAD=master
```

where `unX` is basically the opposite of whatever was changed in X: if some lines were added, delete them; if some lines were changed, put them back the way they were, etc.

Pushing this to the github `origin` system will add the new `unX` commit there, and then `pull`ing on the server will pick up `unX` and the systems will all be in sync.

(You can restore `X` and then revert, so that what you "should" have done becomes what you did do; but at this point it might be just as easy to manually fix the server.)